# What is this binary format for representing dates?

Tags: date, time, encoding, binary

I have been trying to reverse-engineer the way a computer game represents dates in memory. I know I'm looking at the right memory locations, because changing the values in memory changes the dates displayed in the game. However, I'm quite baffled by what I see and want to know if this is a well-established way of representing dates on a computer.

Based on examples like those in the table below, I believe the following to be true:

- The date encoding is based on the number of days since 30th December 1899. This appears to be based on [a wacky old implementation by Microsoft](https://www.iwpcug.org/docs/18991230.php).
- This number, N<sub>days</sub>, is represented in a manner that shows some similarities to floating point. The 32 bits seem to have the following structure: SZEEEEEEEEEENNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN, where:

  - S = Sign bit
  - Z = Always '1', except when |N<sub>days</sub>| is very small?
  - E = Signed 10-bit integer, describing the number of bits (minus 2) required to represent N<sub>days</sub>.
  - N = Signed (E+1)-bit integer representing |N<sub>days</sub>| with the MSB removed. (The MSB is always '1', except when N<sub>days</sub> = 0). The remaining (19 - E) LSBs of N are all '0'.

As hard as I try, I can't get this to make sense as a `float`. So what is going on?

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Date (DD/MM/YYYY) ║ Days since 30/12/1899 ║ 4-byte code (hex) ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 26/11/2001        ║                 37221 ║ 40 E2 2C A0       ║
║ 03/10/1990        ║                 33149 ║ 40 E0 2F A0       ║
║ 16/10/1986        ║                 31701 ║ 40 DE F5 40       ║
║ 04/07/1980        ║                 29406 ║ 40 DC B7 80       ║
║ 15/07/1950        ║                 18459 ║ 40 D2 06 C0       ║
║ 27/06/1939        ║                 14423 ║ 40 CC 2B 80       ║
║ 17/11/1928        ║                 10549 ║ 40 C4 9A 80       ║
║ 05/06/1916        ║                  6001 ║ 40 B7 71 00       ║
║ 23/02/1906        ║                  2246 ║ 40 A1 8C 00       ║
║ 01/01/1905        ║                  1828 ║ 40 9C 90 00       ║
║ 17/06/1902        ║                   899 ║ 40 8C 18 00       ║
║ 19/10/1900        ║                   293 ║ 40 72 50 00       ║
║ 27/07/1899        ║                  -156 ║ C0 63 80 00       ║
║ 22/08/1897        ║                  -860 ║ C0 8A E0 00       ║
║ 10/10/1895        ║                 -1542 ║ C0 98 18 00       ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: From your description this sounds like a pretty ordinary floating-point number, only not in IEEE 754 format. And in your case of course with all the bits after the point being zero.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It is very ordinary. It's just a 64-bit `double`, not a 32-bit `float`! It turns out the 4 bytes before this are always all zeros. Thanks for making me double-check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Ole V.V.'s comment, these are ordinary floating point numbers. They are, of course, `double` precision (hence 11 exponent bits). I had neglected to notice that the preceding 4 bytes are always all zero, so these were actually 64-bit "encodings".